# How to check validations for the Ajax pop up JSP page in Struts 1.x

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts

I got some issue during validation of Struts 1.x. I'm opening a JSP page on the Ajax call. In this JSP page (opened popup) if I want to put some validation like user title is required etc, and while submitting the form I'm directly submitting the details to the required action class method. While submitting I'm not using Ajax submit. I also tried with Ajax submit but it didn't work for me. The below code is my action class method and the JSP page:

```
Action class
public ActionForward saveNotificationsFormDetails(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        DynaValidatorActionForm notificationsForm=(DynaValidatorActionForm)form;
        log.info("In saveNotificationsFormDetails method of NotificationsManagementAction");
        String forwardName="failure";
        String filePath = null;
        String webPath = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();     
        User user=null;     
        try
        {
            int userId=0;
            HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
            if(session!=null)
            {
                user=(User)session.getAttribute("user");
                if(user!=null)
                {

                    if(user.isAdmin()==true)
                    {
                        userId=user.getPrimaryKey();
                        log.info("user is admin");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.info("User has no rights to access this page ");
                        return mapping.findForward("userrestricted");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return mapping.findForward("login");    
                }
            }
            log.info("The user id -"+userId+"-- is is requesting to Notification Details.");

            NotificationsDto notificationsDto = new NotificationsDto();
            NotificationsDao notificationsDao = NotificationsDao.getInstance();
            String  title =  (String) notificationsForm.get("title");
            String  content =  (String) notificationsForm.get("content");

            // uploading the file to notifications directory.
            FormFile url =(FormFile)notificationsForm.get("url");
            String fileName = url.getFileName();
            filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/notifications/"+ fileName;

            if(fileName != null && !fileName.equals("")) {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
                outputStream.write(url.getFileData());

                // getting the web path for the uploaded file
                //String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+request.getContextPath();
                webPath =request.getContextPath()+"/notifications/"+url.getFileName();
            }
            String fromDate = (String) notificationsForm.get("fromDate");
            String toDate = (String) notificationsForm.get("toDate");
            String notifyUsersFlag = (String) notificationsForm.get("notifyUsersFlag");

            boolean notifyUsers = (notifyUsersFlag!=null && notifyUsersFlag.trim().length() > 0 && ( (notifyUsersFlag.trim().equals("on")) || (notifyUsersFlag.trim().equals("true")) ) ) ? true : false;

            //code written for sending the mails to user, if user click on notification checkbox

            if(notifyUsers){
                //NotificationEmailDispatcherJob();
                UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
                try {

                    Properties pro = new Properties();
                    InputStream in = PropertiesFileReader.getInstance().getInputStreamInstance("mail.properties");
                    pro.load(in);
                    String basePath = pro.getProperty("basePath");


                    // Algorithm Steps:
                    /*
                     * Step1: Get all the notifications which are still available to show.
                     * Step2: If notifications size > 0 do the steps(3,4,5) else stop processing.
                     * Step3: Get all users registered and activated in prep511.
                     * Step4: Prepare email content to be sent for each user.
                     * Step5: Validate the email content and send it to user. 
                     */ 

                    // Get all the notifications which are still available to show.
                    List<NotificationsDto> notifications = NotificationsDao.getInstance().getDisplayNotifications();


                    if(notifications !=null && notifications.size() > 0){
                        List<User> activatedUsers = userDao.getAllUsersForAnnoucement();

                        for (Iterator<NotificationsDto> iterator = notifications.iterator(); iterator
                                .hasNext();) {
                            notificationsDto =  iterator.next();
                            Iterator<User> usersIterator = activatedUsers.iterator();
                            while( usersIterator.hasNext() ) {
                                user =  usersIterator.next();

                                String emailContent = getEmailContent(user, basePath, notificationsDto);

                                //verify the emailContent for validness before sendig email.

                                if(emailContent !=null && emailContent.trim().length()>0 && !emailContent.contains("Due to internal server problems your request could not be completed.") && emailContent.contains("Wayne Jones") ){
                                    // send email
                                    String subject = "Prep511 Announcement: "+notificationsDto.getTitle();
                                    sendAnnouncementEmail(pro, basePath, user, emailContent, subject);

                                }
                                else{
                                    // send an email or notification to ven regarding the exception.
                                    // continue for other users.
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            /*if(title == null || title.equals("")){
                ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage("NotificationForm.title.required");
                messages.add("NotificationForm.title.required", message);//jsp
                saveMessages(request, messages);
                return mapping.findForward("NotificationForm.title.required");
            } */

            content = content.replace("\n", "<br />");
            notificationsForm.set("path",filePath);

            notificationsDto.setTitle(title);
            notificationsDto.setContent(content);
            notificationsDto.setFromDate(DateUtils.convertDateFormat(fromDate, "MMM dd, yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", false) );
            notificationsDto.setToDate(DateUtils.convertDateFormat(toDate, "MMM dd, yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", false) );
            notificationsDto.setUrl(webPath);
            notificationsDto.setCreatedBy(user);
            notificationsDto.setLastModifiedBy(user);
            notificationsDto.setNotifyUsersFlag(notifyUsers);
            notificationsDto = notificationsDao.insertRecord(notificationsDto);

            if (notificationsDto.getNotificationsId() > 0 ) {
                //forward to notificationsList.jsp
                // reload notifications
                ServletContext application = this.getServlet().getServletContext();
                new NotificationsLoader().reloadNotifications(application);

                return mapping.findForward("success");
            } else {
                // forward display VendorForm
                // Add action message also
                //record insertion failed.
                ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage("request.process.failed");// resources.properties
                messages.add("request.process.failed", message);//jsp
                saveMessages(request, messages);
                return mapping.findForward(forwardName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return mapping.findForward(forwardName);
        }
    }


jsp page code is and it is a child page ..

<html:form action="processNotifications.do?processName=saveNotificationsFormDetails" styleId="NotificationForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

            <%-- <html:form action="/processNotifications" styleId="NotificationForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> --%> 

                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="1" class="tabcont">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Title<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                    <html:text property="title" styleClass="registration_form_text1"></html:text>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Content<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <html:textarea property="content" styleClass="registration_form_textArea"></html:textarea>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">Url</td>
                    <td>
                        <html:file property="url" />
                   <%--<html:text property="url" styleClass="registration_form_text"></html:text> --%>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">From Date<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                    <td><html:text property="fromDate" styleClass="registration_form_text1" styleId="fromDate" style="autocomplete:off"></html:text>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">To Date<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                    <td>                   
                        <html:text property="toDate" styleClass="registration_form_text1" styleId="toDate" style="autocomplete:off"></html:text>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>                   
                        <html:checkbox property="notifyUsersFlag" styleId="notifyUsersFlag" ></html:checkbox>&nbsp; Notify All Users.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2"  align="left">
                   <%--  <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="submitNotificationForm();">  --%>
                   <input type="submit" value="Save">
                    </td>
                  </tr>               
                  </table>               
              </html:form>

the required ajax call for calling this page is in parent class and the code for this is ........

function displayNotificationForm(){
        var basePath='<%=basePath%>';
        j("#notificationFormDetails").html(waitImage);
        j('#notificationFormDetails').dialog('open');
        j('#notificationFormDetails').dialog('option', 'title', 'Add Home Page Announcement');

        j.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "notifications.do?processName=displayNotificationsFormDetails",
        success : function(data) {
             j("#notificationFormDetails").html(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("error" + textStatus);
            j("#notificationFormDetails").dialog('close');
        }

        });
    }
```